# Split before the appearance of a time/ the appearance of a certain format of characters

Tags: python, split

I have a very large string of data in the following format which I am trying to split in Python:

```
05:38:14.01  M654  P15-17  Tnow  32  PyQ  64  Times  67  49  6005:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow  60  PyQ  64  Times  55  4405:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow   8  PyQ  64  Times  26  1505:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow  60  PyQ  64  Times  54  4505:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow   8  PyQ  64  Times  37   1  2005:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow  28  Ncyt  64  Times  55  44
```

The `:` are part of a time (e.g. `05:38:14`) but the two numbers before the time are related to the previous line of data. Therefore, I want to be able to split the string before the time so that it reads as follows:

```
05:38:14.01  M654  P15-17  Tnow  32  PyQ  64  Times  67  49  60

05:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow  60  PyQ  64  Times  55  44

05:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow   8  PyQ  64  Times  26  15

05:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow  60  PyQ  64  Times  54  45

05:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow   8  PyQ  64  Times  37   1  20

05:38:14.01  M654  P15-17   Tnow  28  Ncyt  64  Times  55  44
```

etc.

I have tried splitting it every *n* number of characters but each line had a different number.

Also the numbers I want to be able to split it at are different throughout the data set as the time changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
parts = [x for x in re.compile('([\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}.[\d]{2})').split(s) if x]

Output
['05:38:14.01',
 ' M654 P15-17 Tnow 32 PyQ 64 Times 67 49 60',
 '05:38:14.01',
 ' M654 P15-17 Tnow 60 PyQ 64 Times 55 44',
 '05:38:14.01',
 ' M654 P15-17 Tnow 8 PyQ 64 Times 26 15',
 '05:38:14.01',
 ' M654 P15-17 Tnow 60 PyQ 64 Times 54 45',
 '05:38:14.01',
 ' M654 P15-17 Tnow 8 PyQ 64 Times 37 1 20',
 '05:38:14.01',
 ' M654 P15-17 Tnow 28 Ncyt 64 Times 55 44']
```

This will split at every occurrence of the regex that matches the timestamp, where s is your string.

Then join pairwise the timestamp item of the list with the text item.

```
strings = ["".join(parts[i] + parts[i+1]) for i in range(len(parts) - 1)[::2]]

Output
['05:38:14.01 M654 P15-17 Tnow 32 PyQ 64 Times 67 49 60',
 '05:38:14.01 M654 P15-17 Tnow 60 PyQ 64 Times 55 44',
 '05:38:14.01 M654 P15-17 Tnow 8 PyQ 64 Times 26 15',
 '05:38:14.01 M654 P15-17 Tnow 60 PyQ 64 Times 54 45',
 '05:38:14.01 M654 P15-17 Tnow 8 PyQ 64 Times 37 1 20',
 '05:38:14.01 M654 P15-17 Tnow 28 Ncyt 64 Times 55 44']
```

There might be a oneliner solution with a more sophisticated regex. I'm not great at regex sorry.